# c++ differing outputs of method depending on position in code

Tags: c++

I am a have a problem with the following code. Basically I am getting unexpected output when I put the method `size()` directly in an expression. When I run the method and assign its output to a variable and then use that variable in the expression I no longer have the problem.

When I run this code with my debugger

```
      Line * line_cf = music.getLine("cf");
      ... some other code ...
      {                                                
        int lsize = line_cf->size();
        double r2 = abs(36-(line_cf->size()));          
      }
```

I get a strange value for r2

```
lsize      -> 39
r2         -> 1.8446744073709552e+19
```

If I instead run this code

```
      Line * line_cf = music.getLine("cf");
      ... some other code ...
      {                                                
        int lsize = line_cf->size();
        double r2 = abs(36-lsize);      // <--- 
      }
```

I get the expected value for `r2`

```
lsize      -> 39
r2         -> 3
```

Line is a user-defined class.

```
class Line : std::list<TonalNote> {
 public:
  std::string id;
  MusicStyle style;
};
```

Update 1:

I tried removing the first line within the brackets, so I now have the following code.

```
      Line * line_cf = music.getLine("cf");
      ... some other code ...
      {                                                
        double r2 = abs(36-(line_cf->size()));          
      }
```

Still getting the same strange value for `r2`. So I think this eliminates the possibility that `Line::size()` is changing its own state.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen. You've probably got a bug with undefined behavior somewhere in your code that might be completely unrelated to what you've shown. Using valgrind might give you a clue.

Comment: Probably it would be better if you could post a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)... For one thing, your definition of Line should be `class Line : public std::list<TonalNote> { ... }` .... otherwise the rest of the world will not be able to access the `size()` method from list... (unless you have you're own `size()` method... in which case we will need to look at it).

Comment: can u post code for `Line::size()`? My guess is calling this method changes the internal state of `Line` object, hence it returns garbage for subsequent call.

Comment: I am not eliminating any code at all inside the scope brackets that I show. This is exactly the code I am debugging with gdb. And I do not reimplement size() in class Line. It is just the inherited function from std::list.

Comment: no errors from valgrind happening before or at this code. first error from valgrind is much later in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost certain that `line_cf->size()` returns an object of type `size_t`. If you write,

```
size_t lsize = line_cf->size();
double r2 = abs(36-lsize);
```

You will get the same large number.

The reason for that is `(36-lsize)` will evaluate to a value that is of type `size_t`, and a very large one when `lsize` is `39`.

When you store the returned value of `line_cf->size()` in an `int` and use that variable in `(36-lsize)`, you get a signed integer subtraction result, which works in a more sensible manner.

Comment: I think this is correct. When I cast `line_cf->size()` to an int I get the correct result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`size()` is returning a 64-bit unsigned integer, so the subtraction `36 - (line_cf->size())` is occurring in the 64-bit unsigned integer type, resulting in arithmetic wraparound to `2^64`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << static_cast<double>(std::fabs(36 - 39ull));
}
```

prints `1.84467e+19`.

To ensure signed arithmetic occurs, replace the constant `36` with `36ll`, or cast `line_cf->size()` to `int` (this is what happens in your second code excerpt):

```
    double r2 = abs(36-static_cast<int>(line_cf->size()));   
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```